# Unable to override bash startup script in sbt-native-packager

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I'm working with Scala on SBT 0.13.6 and sbt-native-packager 1.0.0-M3

The project is destined to build AKKA kernel project using AkkaAppPackaging Archetype. According to the sbt-native-packager documentation I should be able to override bash script templates for each archetype if I place them in [projectdir]/src/main/templates. I placed modified akka-bash-template in that directory but it is not taken into account.

Any suggestions on how to deal with this issue?

Comment: What does this have to do with `bash`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you put it into the wrong directory. Try

```
[projectdir]/src/templates
```

See [Adding Configuration](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/archetypes/cheatsheet.html#overriding-templates)

Comment: Did this work? I think I am trying similar.  Can you please explain solution (Link to Adding Configuration does not seem to work).

Comment: I updated the link. You have to override the standard bash template by putting the template in the right directory as described.